# Google Drive upload without every time authorization?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Is there any way to not require every time authorization from user? Every time I want to upload a file I need to log in to my Google account, confirm and after this I'm able go further. I'm using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Comment: I believe this was put into the drive sdk for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to ask users every time you want to upload file once user authorized access.
Once you get authorized by user, along with `access_token`, you will get `refresh_token` which you can save and use whenever you want to regenerate `access_token`.

Take a close look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/training/drive-apps/auth/credentials) for more details including working php code.